# Error faced in creating database The style compilation failed, see the error below

Tags: html, web, odoo

Error:
The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made.

```
Could not get content for /web_dialog_size/static/src/css/web_dialog_size.css defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you get given error then follow the below steps:

```
Apps -> web_dialog_size -> uninstall module
```

If you need this module then again install it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried upgrading first and that worked after